# Bash: most concise way to read a string of space into two variables

Tags: bash

I have a string variable `line="foo bar"`. I want to read it into two variables, `$foo` and `$bar`.

My code doesn't work:

```
read foo bar < <($line)
```

This results in:

```
-bash: foo: command not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
read -r foo bar <<< "$line"
```

- `<(list)`: this is called a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). The list is executed and the output is then referred to using a filename. `$line` expands to `foo bar`, `bash` then tries to execute `foo` with one argument, `bar`. Thus the error `foo: command not found`
- `<<< word`: this is called a [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). `word` gets expanded and the result is supplied as a single string with a newline appended. `$line` expands to `"foo bar"` and is correctly supplied to the `read` command
- `-r`: used so that `read` doesn't mangle any backslashes

You could also change your code like this (here string is better):

```
read -r foo bar < <(echo "$line")
```